# Commerce: are Shipping prices always assumed to include tax?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce3

A client is asking if the order calculation can show a 20% tax calculation on the shipping price.

From looking through Commerce 3, it seems this isn't possible, eg Shipping prices are always assumed to be inclusive of tax?

Comment: Hey @james-greig, have you found out something here? It does not make sense that shipping is without tax. We are having this problem too and we need a solution for this as well.

Comment: See answer below @SimonFranzen should help!

Answer (score 2):

We fixed this by doing three things...

1. On our tax rate, setting "Taxable Subject" to "Order total taxable price (Line item subtotal + Total discounts + Total shipping)"
2. Also on our tax rate, turning *on* the "Is this tax is already
   included in the taxable subject?" switch.
3. In our templates, wherever tax is displayed, changing from `{{getTotalTax}}` to `{{getTotalTaxIncluded}}` — eg to display the total tax (included) on a basket for both line items and shipping you'd want something like `{{ cart.getTotalTaxIncluded('tax')|commerceCurrency(cart.currency) }}`

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Thanks man! We try it tomorrow!